# can not build kotlin project with android studio

Tags: android

When I first create a kotlin project, it failed and show the exception below!

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I can't even see the full error in the screenshot. That's why it should be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace google and jcenter order on your gradle like:

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

first google than jcenter

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, had to go back to Kotlin 1.2.61 !
Then it worked again. Give it a try

Edit: Btw. mentioned here, but already update available for 1.2.71
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/?utm_source=android-studio&utm_medium=studio-assistant